# Socket.accept() freezing loop and returning nothing using socket in python

Tags: python, sockets, networking, server

```
class connectedclient():
  def __init__(self,conn,ip,privatekey):
    self.udpsocket = ip
    self.tcpsocket = conn
    self.privatekey = privatekey
    self.connectedfully = False

class server():
  def __init__(self,IP):
    self.socketip = convertipwithport(IP)
    self.tcpsocketip = (self.socketip[0],self.socketip[1] + 1)

    self.nextplayerid = 0

    self.tcpserversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.tcpserversocket.bind(self.tcpsocketip)
    self.tcpserversocket.listen()

    self.udpserversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    self.udpserversocket.bind(self.socketip)

    self.qeuedmessages = []
    self.connectedclients = []
    self.maxrecvbytes = 1024
    self.pubkey,self.privkey = rsa.newkeys(1024)

  def handlemessage(self,message):
    ipee = message[1]
    msg = message[0]
    for v in self.connectedclients:
      if v.udpsocket == ipee:
        if v.connectedfully == True:
          msg = rsa.decrypt(base64.b64decode(msg),self.privatekey).decode()
        

  def handleserver(self):
    for iteration in range(9999999):
      conn,addr = self.tcpserversocket.accept()
      if conn != None:
        clien = connectedclient(conn,addr,self.privkey)
        self.connectedclients.append(clien)
        clien.tcpsocket.sendall(self.pubkey)
      else:
        break
    for iteration in range(9999999):
      messages = self.udpserversocket.recvfrom(self.maxrecvbytes)
      print("help")
      if messages != None:
        self.handlemessage(messages)
      else:
        break #break because its done processing all the incoming packets and is ready for the next set.
    for clien in self.connectedclients:
      dat = b""
      for v in range(9999999):
        datea = clien.tcpsocket.recv(1024)
        if datea != None and datea != b"":
          dat = dat+datea
      dat = dat.decode()
      datatable = []
      for v in dat:
        data += v
        if v == "}":
          if c < len(dat):
            if dat[c] == "{":
              try:
                dat = json.loads(data)
              except:
                continue
              datatable.append(dat)
              data = ""
          else:
            try:
              
              dat = json.loads(data)
            except:
              continue
            datatable.append(dat)
            data = ""
        c += 1
      
      for v in datatable:
        if v['PT'] == "CR": #PT == "packettype" CR == "Client ready"
          clien.connectedfully = True
```

Im really frustrated with this because everything I have tried hasnt worked, i commented out the part thats giving me issues and it works, but it so happens the part i comment out is the most crucial part...

I tried placing prints after the .accept() and it doesn't print, i tried turning this from a class to a function, i tried putting the handle server function into just one loop, nothing worked.

Comment: accept will wait and block until a client connects ... then it will continue...

Comment: If you want to find out if `accept()` will block or not, you can `select()` on `self.tcpserversocket` to find out if it is ready-for-read.  If it *is* ready-for-read, that means a TCP connection is ready to be accepted as soon as you call `accept()`; if it is not ready-for-read, that means that no incoming TCP connction is currently pending, so an `accept()` call will block until one arrives.

Comment: Assuming you are on linux then @JeremyFriesner is correct ... afaik it does not work on windows (but i could easily be wrong on that count)

Comment: @JoranBeasley I use this technique in Python scripts under Windows, and I can attest that it does work there.

Comment: How would you run select() on the socket? is it in a module or what? sorry im still pretty new to sockets.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html

Comment: Don't bind to your own IP address. Bind to 0.0.0.0.

Comment: `select()` did not work on it, it just made it so that nothing still would connect but it would go on with the loop